# Send data from one view to another - Lumen (AMP)

Tags: php, routes, lumen, amp-html

I am trying to send data from one view to another without controllers in Lumen. The flow works like this:

1) User Selects a Product variation
 2) amp-bind adds the
    values*(price,name and ClientID)* to hidden fields
 3) User
    clicks on "Add to Cart"
 4) A Form submission is done, the
    `routes.php` gets the data on route`"add-to-cart"`
 5) The
    route"add-to-cart" then uses AMP-Redirect-To so the user gets
    redirected to another view in `routes.php` that is called `"cart"`.
    (i var_dump the $response and i get the variables *(name, price and
    ClientId)*
 6) In the route `"cart"` the ***data is not available
    now***. i did `var_dump($response)` but got nothing, where is the
    data missed. The code is under:

**View:**

```
<form id="order"
          method="POST"
          action-xhr="/amp/proteinfabrikken/add-to-cart"
          target="_top"
          class="flex flex-wrap m1">
                    <div class="items-center flex my1">
                        <input type="submit"
                               class="ampstart-btn caps"
                               name="add-to-cart"
                               value="add to cart">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="name"
                           [value]=" variationSelect.variations.filter(x => x.variation_id == selected_variation)[0].name">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="price"
                           [value]="variationSelect.variations.filter(x => x.variation_id == selected_variation)[0].selling_price">
                    <input name="clientId"
                           type="hidden"
                           value="CLIENT_ID(cart)"
                           data-amp-replace="CLIENT_ID">
                    <div submit-error>
                        <template type="amp-mustache">
                            Error! Looks like something went wrong with your shopping cart, please try to add an item again. {{error}}
                        </template>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

**Routes.php:**

```
$app->post($prefix . '/add-to-cart', function (Request $request, Response $response) {


    $name = $request->request->get('name');
    $price = $request->request->get('price');
    $clientId = $request->request->get('clientId');


    return response()
        ->json(['name' => $name, 'price' => $price,'clientId' => $clientId])
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*.ampproject.org')
        ->header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin', Util::getFullPath(""))
        ->header('AMP-Redirect-To', 'http://localhost:1332/amp/proteinfabrikken/cart')
        ->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin, AMP-Redirect-To');



});

$app->get($prefix . '/cart', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    echo "<pre>";
    return var_dump($request);
});
```

`return var_dump($request)` is empty in `'/cart'`

Could someone see the problem?